# DTE selectedItems Project field in null when

Tags: c#, envdte

I'm using dte in order to get the path to a file I right-clicked on in VS extension.
I used SelectedItems like in here: [SelectedItem.DTE Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.selecteditem.dte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

However, the Project field is always null when testing.
I'm testing on another solution in which I added a file with Add->Add Existing item into a project, so I don't see any reason why it return null.
Had it happened to someone? How can I get the full path of the selected item then?

EDIT: code example of what I want to do

```
selItem = dte.SelectedItems.Item(1);  
var t = selItem.Name;   // this works fine
var t2 = selItem.Project;  // this return null
var t2= selItem.ProjectItem;  // this also return null
```

Comment: Add some line of code which will help the community to understand the problem

Comment: thanks, I added a code example